# Using a Power-on and Shutdown button with the HyperPixel4 touchscreen

Tags: pi-4, power-management

I am trying to wire up my Raspberry Pi 4B to have BOTH the HyperPixel4 touchscreen and a power-on button as well as a shutdown button (From my understanding I cannot have [one for both operations](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/LoPwrOneButtonStartStop.md) because I need Low Power Mode enabled).

This raises some challenges, as the HyperPixel screen uses [every single GPIO pin](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/hyperpixel4) available.

I was able to follow [Seamus Demora's guide](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/RPi4bSleep.md) to wire up a Startup button to GLOBAL_EN, which seems to work as expected.

For shutdown, I wanted to know if there was a way to use the alternate i2c interface provided by the [HyperPixel screen](https://learn.pimoroni.com/article/getting-started-with-hyperpixel-4#using-the-alternate-i2c-interface-on-hyperpixel-4-0-for-advanced-users) to wire up a separate button?

Specifically, is it possible to do this using the [dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/45319db29eb5e4f67feab5c4194bc1f28c574ed0/boot/overlays/README#L1619) overlay, or would I need to write some kind of python script to listen for the alternate i2c interface?

Comment: You can use ANY pin with that overlay. It DOESN'T use i2c. I use GPIO21.

Comment: Okay so if it's not one of the gpio pins soldered to the board gpio-shutdown is not an option?